# Calculating Discount Margin on a floating rate bond using QuantLib

Tags: programming, quantlib, forward-rate, floating-rate, discount-factor-curve

Going off Luigi's hint on this answer: [Setting up Schedule for an amortizing floater in QuantLib](https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/8965/setting-up-schedule-for-an-amortizing-floater-in-quantlib)

I was able to cobble something together but I'm unable to verify if it's correct.  TLDR: I was able to generate [this cashflow](https://drive.google.com/open?id=10uKA3v7nbwDYSu8PjJfpSzQK04V6gGfo) and got a Discount Margin value of **121.42091071060361** for the price input of 90.00.  Any insights is appreciated.

First, let's set up the bond:  It's a LIBOR+1.77 (vectors come from a third party).

- Issue Date: 03/06/1997
- Maturity: 03/06/2037
- Next payment: 03/05/2018
- Face: 12000000
- Floater: 1.77
- Reference Index: LIBOR_1MO (vectors: https://pastebin.com/HLYWsyux)

**Setting up the bond:**  I use `InterpolatedForwardCurve` to setup my floating rates vectors and feed it to `ForwardSpreadedTermStructure` in order to accept a spread value.  The basic idea is that since `SimpleQuote`, your input spread, is an observable, all changes to it will trigger recalculations in your bond class.  I use this input in order to find the spread at which price exactly equals the current price (the price is an input; going from price **to get** DM).

**DMFinder Function:** My DMFinder inherits ISolver1d accepts a price as input.  The `value(x)` implementation accepts a Spread value and tries to solve for `v` where the the resulting price exactly matches the original price; i.e. the spread value where the price exactly results in a null price at the current DM.  As advised by @LuigiBallabio I'm also keeping an instance of the Bond class inside the `DMFinder` class to call `cleanPrice()` as the `SimpleQuote` value changes.

```
private class DMFinder : ISolver1d
{
    private readonly FloatingRateBond bond_;
    private SimpleQuote spread_;
    private double price_;

    public DMFinder(FloatingRateBond bond, double price, SimpleQuote spread)
    {
        this.bond_ = bond;
        this.price_ = price;
        this.spread_ = spread;
    }

    public override double value(double v)
    {
        this.spread.setValue(v);
        var solvedPrice = bond.cleanPrice();
        return this.price - solvedPrice;
    }
}
```

**Getting the DM through Solver1D:**

```
public static double DM(FloatingRateBond bond, double price, SimpleQuote spread, double accuracy = 1.0e-10, int maxIterations = 100, double guess = 0.05)
{
    var solver = new FiniteDifferenceNewtonSafe();
    solver.SetMaxEvaluations(maxIterations);

    var objFunction = new DMFinder(bond, price, spread);
    var dm = solver.Solve(objFunction, accuracy, guess, guess / 10.0);
    return dm;
}
```

**Full bond setup:**  Full code below.

```
var settleDate = new Date(15, Month.Jan, 2018);                         // Settle date
var settlementDays = 3;                                                 // Settle day number, usually T+3
var faceAmount = 12000000.00;                                           // Current face
var issueDate = new Date(3, Month.Jun, 1997);                           // Issue Date
var maturity = new Date(3, Month.Jun, 2037);                            // Maturity Date

var thirty360 = new Thirty360();                                        // Day counter, using 30/360 convention.
var calendar = new UnitedStates(UnitedStates.Market.Settlement);        // Using USA settlement calendar for holidays/weekends detection
settleDate = calendar.adjust(settleDate);

// Evaluation must be a business day
var today = calendar.advance(settleDate, -settlementDays, TimeUnit.Days);
Settings.setEvaluationDate(today);      // Set business day to today

// An observable, holds the Spread argument
var spread = new SimpleQuote(0.0);

// Vectors are here: https://pastebin.com/HLYWsyux
var yieldCurve = new InterpolatedForwardCurve<Linear>(VECTOR_DATES, VECTORS, thirty360, calendar, new Linear());
yieldCurve.enableExtrapolation();
var spreadedYieldCurve = new ForwardSpreadedTermStructure(new Handle<YieldTermStructure>(yieldCurve), new Handle<Quote>(spread));
spreadedYieldCurve.enableExtrapolation();

var discountingTs = new Handle<YieldTermStructure>(spreadedYieldCurve);
var indexTs = new Handle<YieldTermStructure>(spreadedYieldCurve);

var index = new Libor("USD Libor",          // Family name
    new Period(Frequency.Monthly),          // Frequency of of rates
    2,                                      // Settlement days
    new USDCurrency(),                      // Base currency
    calendar,                               // Calendar used
    thirty360,                              // Day counting convention
    indexTs);                               // Class containing vectors and dates, as well as interpolation

// Generates the payment schedule, always start at issue date
var schedule = new Schedule(issueDate,
    maturity,
    new Period(Frequency.Quarterly),
    calendar,
    BusinessDayConvention.ModifiedFollowing,
    BusinessDayConvention.ModifiedFollowing,
    DateGeneration.Rule.Forward,
    false);

// Setup the bond, issued 06/03/1997, libor+177, matures 06/03/2037
// Next payment: 03/05/2018
var bond = new FloatingRateBond(settlementDays,
    faceAmount,
    schedule,
    index,
    thirty360,
    schedule.businessDayConvention(),
    0,                                  // Fixing days
    new List<double>() { 1, 1.0 },      // LIBOR multiplier (for example, 0.80 * libor)
    new List<double>() { 1, 0.0177 },   // The spread, or "libor plus" => in this case,  x is 0.0177
    new List<double?>() { },            // Caps
    new List<double?>() { },            // Floors
    true,                               // Index fixing in arrears?
    100,                                // Percent of redemption at maturity
    issueDate);                         // When bond was issued

var bondEngine = new DiscountingBondEngine(discountingTs);
bond.setPricingEngine(bondEngine);

// Sets the coupon pricer to the bond
var pricer = new BlackIborCouponPricer();
var vol = 0.0;
var volatility = new ConstantOptionletVolatility(3,
    calendar,
    BusinessDayConvention.ModifiedFollowing,
    vol,
    new Thirty360());

pricer.setCapletVolatility(new Handle<OptionletVolatilityStructure>(volatility));
HelperFunctions.setCouponPricer(bond.cashflows(), pricer);

// now calculate DM
var dm = Cashflows.DM(bond, 90, spread) * 100;
```

Comment: What if you use `yieldCurve` instead of `spreadedYieldCurve` for discounting?  Does the result make more sense?

Comment: @LuigiBallabio It didn't work for me because it takes into account `Spreads` in the DM calculations.  I needed a way to calculate DM without Spreads.  See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

**Update (2018-10-09):**

This solution is more correct.  It's a class that solves for the DM using the class `ForwardSpreadedTermStructure`.

```
public class DMFinder : ISolver1d
{
    private readonly List<Cashflow> leg_;
    private readonly double dm_;
    private readonly DayCounter dayCounter_;
    private readonly Compounding compounding_;
    private readonly Frequency frequency_;
    private readonly bool includeSettlementDateFlows_;
    private readonly Date settlementDate_, npvDate_;
    private readonly Handle<YieldTermStructure> discountCurve_;
    private readonly ForwardSpreadedTermStructure forwardSpreadedTs_;
    private readonly SimpleQuote spread_;

    public DMFinder(List<Cashflow> leg,
        double dm,
        Handle<YieldTermStructure> discountCurve,
        DayCounter dayCounter,
        Compounding comp,
        Frequency freq,
        bool includeSettlementDateFlows,
        Date settlementDate,
        Date npvDate)
    {
        leg_ = leg;
        dm_ = dm;
        dayCounter_ = dayCounter;
        compounding_ = comp;
        frequency_ = freq;
        includeSettlementDateFlows_ = includeSettlementDateFlows;
        settlementDate_ = settlementDate;
        npvDate_ = npvDate;
        discountCurve_ = discountCurve;

        if (settlementDate_ == null) settlementDate_ = Settings.EvaluationDate();
        if (npvDate_ == null) npvDate_ = settlementDate_;

        // Get the spread, starting at 0.0
        // This will value will be what the solver will try to solve for
        spread_ = new SimpleQuote(0.0);

        // Declare a new Spreaded Discount Curve using the given curve and the spread
        forwardSpreadedTs_ = new ForwardSpreadedTermStructure(discountCurve_, new Handle<Quote>(spread_));
        forwardSpreadedTs_.EnableExtrapolation(discountCurve_.Instance.AllowsExtrapolation());
    }

    public override double Value(double v)
    {
        // The solver will set the value v continuously until a solution is found
        this.spread_.SetValue(v);
        var solvedDm = Cashflows.DM(leg_, forwardSpreadedTs_, includeSettlementDateFlows_, settlementDate_, npvDate_);

        return dm_ - solvedDm;
    }
}
```

This function discounts the cashflows given the spread:

```
/// <summary>
/// Given a discount curve, calculate the Discount Margin of the cashflows when
/// discounted against the given curve.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="leg">The schedule of cashflows.</param>
/// <param name="discountCurve">The discount curve that is spreaded via a simple quote.</param>
/// <param name="includeSettlementDateFlows">Specifies whether we want to include settlement date flows.</param>
/// <param name="settlementDate">the settlement date.</param>
/// <param name="npvDate">the npv date.</param>
/// <returns>The total calculated npv</returns>
public static double DM(Leg leg,
    ForwardSpreadedTermStructure discountCurve,
    bool includeSettlementDateFlows,
    Date settlementDate = null,
    Date npvDate = null)
{
    if (leg.Empty()) return 0.0;

    if (settlementDate == null)
        settlementDate = Settings.EvaluationDate();

    if (npvDate == null)
        npvDate = settlementDate;

    var iborCoupon = leg.FirstOrDefault(c => c is IborCoupon);
    double cfSpread = 0.0;
    if (iborCoupon != null)
        cfSpread = (iborCoupon as IborCoupon).Spread();

    // If the cashflow's spread is non-zero, take it away from the quote handler
    // inside the ForwardSpreadedTermStruture
    if(cfSpread > 0.0)
    {
        var dmSpreadHandler = discountCurve.Spread();
        var dmSpread = dmSpreadHandler.Instance.Value();

        // Take the cashflow's spread off of the  discount curve's spread
        // By updating the value, we notify the ForwardSpreadedTermStructure to use the new value
        (dmSpreadHandler.Instance as SimpleQuote).SetValue(dmSpread - cfSpread);
    }

    double totalDm = 0.0;

    // Loop through the cashflows and calculate the total DM, based on the discount curve
    foreach(var period in leg
        .Where(l => !l.HasOccurred(settlementDate, includeSettlementDateFlows))
        .GroupBy(l => l.Date())
        .OrderBy(p => p.Key))
    {
        var date = period.Key;

        // In each period, discount against the curve for each amount
        foreach(var cashflow in period)
        {
            totalDm += cashflow.Amount() * discountCurve.Discount(date);
        }
    }

    return totalDm / discountCurve.Discount(npvDate);
}
```

===

This is what I ended up implementing and has been verified to work by a colleague.

Quite similar to calculating yield, the DM function takes a `cleanPrice` and derives a `dirtyPrice` from the accrued amount.

```
public static double DM(Bond bond,
    double cleanPrice,
    DayCounter dayCounter,
    Compounding compounding,
    Frequency frequency,
    Date settlementDate = null,
    double accuracy = 1.0e-10,
    int maxIterations = 100,
    double guess = 0.05)
{
    if (settlementDate == null)
        settlementDate = bond.SettlementDate();

    Thrower.AssertValid(BondFunctions.IsTradable(bond, settlementDate), () =>
    $"non tradable at {settlementDate} (maturity being {bond.MaturityDate()})");

    double dirtyPrice = cleanPrice + bond.AccruedAmount(settlementDate);
    dirtyPrice /= 100.0 / bond.Notional(settlementDate);

    return Cashflows.DM(bond.Cashflows(), dirtyPrice,
                            dayCounter, compounding, frequency,
                            false, settlementDate, settlementDate,
                            accuracy, maxIterations, guess);
}
```

Once you have the target NPV (the `dirtyPrice`), you feed it to the next function, which does the actual calculations:

```
public static double DM(Leg leg,
    double npv,
    DayCounter dayCounter,
    Compounding compounding,
    Frequency frequency,
    bool includeSettlementDateFlows,
    Date settlementDate = null,
    Date npvDate = null,
    double accuracy = 1.0e-10,
    int maxIterations = 100,
    double guess = 0.05)
{
    var solver = new FiniteDifferenceNewtonSafe();
    solver.SetMaxEvaluations(maxIterations);
    var objFunction = new DMFinder(leg,
        npv,
        dayCounter,
        compounding,
        frequency,
        includeSettlementDateFlows,
        settlementDate,
        npvDate);

    return solver.Solve(objFunction, accuracy, guess, guess / 10.0);
}
```

And this is the `DMFinder` function.  It solves for DM by given a `discountRate` and stops solving when a given `discountRate` results in the original DM (NPV).

```
private class DMFinder : ISolver1d
{
    private Leg leg;
    private double dm;
    private DayCounter dayCounter;
    private Compounding compounding;
    private Frequency frequency;
    private bool includeSettlementDateFlows;
    private Date settlementDate, npvDate;

    public DMFinder(Leg leg,
        double dm,
        DayCounter dayCounter,
        Compounding comp,
        Frequency freq,
        bool includeSettlementDateFlows,
        Date settlementDate,
        Date npvDate)
    {
        this.leg = leg;
        this.dm = dm;
        this.dayCounter = dayCounter;
        this.compounding = comp;
        this.frequency = freq;
        this.includeSettlementDateFlows = includeSettlementDateFlows;
        this.settlementDate = settlementDate;
        this.npvDate = npvDate;

        if (settlementDate == null)
            settlementDate = Settings.EvaluationDate();

        if (npvDate == null)
            this.npvDate = this.settlementDate;
    }

    public override double Value(double v)
    {
        var discountRate = new InterestRate(v, this.dayCounter, this.compounding, this.frequency);
        var solvedDm = Cashflows.DM(this.leg, discountRate, this.includeSettlementDateFlows, this.settlementDate, this.npvDate);
        return this.dm - solvedDm;
    }
}
```

**And Finally, this is where the total DM calc happens.**  This is needed by the solver.  It takes a given `discountRate` and calculates total DM.  Note that it doesn't taken into account the given Spread (the floater margin):

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets the total DM given a discount rate.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="leg">The cashflows.</param>
/// <param name="dm">The discount rate.</param>
/// <param name="includeSettlementDateFlows">Indicates whether to includ cashflows that occurred on the settlement date.</param>
/// <param name="settlementDate">The settlement date.</param>
/// <param name="npvDate">The NPV date.</param>
/// <returns>The total DM.</returns>
public static double DM(Leg leg,
    InterestRate dm,
    bool includeSettlementDateFlows,
    Date settlementDate = null,
    Date npvDate = null)
{
    if (leg.Empty()) return 0.0;

    if (settlementDate == null)
        settlementDate = Settings.EvaluationDate();

    if (npvDate == null)
        npvDate = settlementDate;

    var totalDm = 0.0;
    var discount = 1.0;
    var lastRate = 0.0;
    var lastSpread = 0.0;
    var lastDate = npvDate;
    Date refStartDate, refEndDate;

    for(var i = 0; i< leg.Count; ++i)
    {
        if (leg[i].HasOccurred(settlementDate, includeSettlementDateFlows))
            continue;

        var couponDate = leg[i].Date();
        var amount = leg[i].Amount();
        if (leg[i].TradingExCoupon(settlementDate))
            amount = 0.0;

        var coupon = leg[i] as Coupon;
        if(coupon != null)
        {
            refStartDate = coupon.ReferencePeriodStart;
            refEndDate = coupon.ReferencePeriodEnd;
        }
        else
        {
            if (lastDate == npvDate)
            {
                // we don't have a previous coupon date,
                // so we fake it
                refStartDate = couponDate - new Period(1, TimeUnit.Years);
            }
            else
            {
                refStartDate = lastDate;
            }
            refEndDate = couponDate;
        }

        double l, h;
        if (settlementDate > refStartDate && settlementDate < refEndDate)
            l = dm.DayCounter().YearFraction(settlementDate, refEndDate, refStartDate, refEndDate);
        else
        {
            l = dm.DayCounter().YearFraction(lastDate, couponDate, refStartDate, refEndDate);
            // if (coupon != null) l = coupon.AccrualPeriod();
            // else l = dm.DayCounter().YearFraction(lastDate, couponDate, refStartDate, refEndDate);
        }

        double rate;
        if (coupon != null) rate = coupon.Rate();
        else rate = lastRate; // Fake the last rate if the coupon doesn't come with a rate

        var spread = 0.0;
        if ((leg[i] as IborCoupon) != null) spread = (leg[i] as IborCoupon).Spread();
        else spread = lastSpread;

        h = rate + dm.Rate() - spread;
        discount /= (1 + (l * h));

        totalDm += discount * amount;

        lastDate = couponDate;
        lastRate = rate;
        lastSpread = spread;
    }

    return totalDm;
}
```

Comment: I see.  So during the solving phase, you move the discounting curve but keep the coupon amounts fixed; my code was moving both.  One doubt: as far as I can see, your solver seems to return the discount rate directly, much like what a yield calculation would do.  Isn't the discount margin supposed to be a spread over libor?

Comment: @LuigiBallabio See my edit, the **Total DM** calc.  On the line `h = rate + dm.Rate() - spread;`, I needed to get the rate without the coupon's spread.  I don't know why my coworker prefered this way... But he needed to see the DM without the floater margin.

Comment: That's because the rate minus the coupon spread is the libor.  The rate you're using for discounting is `libor + dm.Rate()`, which makes `dm.Rate()` a spread over libor.  This looks similar to what you would get from your original code if you wrote `var discountingTs = new Handle<YieldTermStructure>(spreadedYieldCurve);` and 
`var indexTs = new Handle<YieldTermStructure>(yieldCurve);` in the bond setup.  Out of curiosity, may you try it and see if the figure you get is in the right ballpark?

Comment: @LuigiBallabio Please see update.  Turns out using the `ForwardSpreadedTermStructure` as you suggest is the correct way.